# Is there a way to convert curried functions to uncurried functions?

Tags: rescript

The map function in rescript-json-combinators accepts only uncurried functions and the functions we are using are curried.
What is the best way to go around this? I don't know if there is a way to convert curried functions to unccuried functions or if I should create a new map function that accepts curried functions.

Some exapmles of a solution I have tried :

**Before:**

```
        input'(
          list{
            type'("text"),
            on(~key="", "input", Json.Decode.map(v => v |> int_of_string |> set_value, targetValue)),
          },
          list{},
        ),
```

**After:**

```
         input'(
          list{
            type'("text"),
            on(~key="", "input",((. v) => v |> int_of_string |> set_value)|> Json.Decode.map(targetValue)),
          },
          list{},
        ),`
```

Is this a correct way to solve this issue?

This solution wouldn't always work, couldn't figure out what to do in other cases.

**Example:**

```
let onMouseDown = onCB("mousedown", ~key= "", ev =>
  decodeEvent(
    map(Mouse.position, dragStart),
    ev,
  ) |> Tea_result.resultToOption
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, converting a function from curried to uncurried, or vice versa, is just a matter of creating an anonymous function with one calling convention, calling a function with the other calling convention:

```
// curried to uncurried
v => f(. v)

// uncurried to curried
(. v) => f(v)
```

In your example it would be:

```
map(Mouse.position, (. v) => dragStart(v))
```

Comment: I made a mistake in the order of the arguments in the post. dragStart is the function so it would be  
```map( Mouse.position, (. v) =>dragStart(v))```
Thank you!

Comment: That does make more sense :)

Comment: // uncurried to curried
(. v) => f(v)
wouldn't this be curried to uncurried since we are trying to use an uncurried function inside the map function ?

Comment: Depends on perspective I guess :) My perspective here is that it takes a curried function, `f`, and makes it uncurried.